# How iterate str and int at time in any variable in python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I am getting some names and car_no from sql queries and want to iterate them in my other "msg" variable.

```
car_no = <class 'int'>
names = <class 'str'>

input sample: names & car_no
jhon
198
pig
144
carlet
36
Mona
144
rahul
510
```

like that 100 names and car_no is there, want to iterate all this names and car_no in msg.(that msg is for send mail to recipents(HTML format))
Required output is:

```
<html>
                                 <head></head>
                                 <body>
                                   <p>Dear jhon</p>
                                   <p>your bday list:</br>
                                     jhon - 199</br>
                                      pig - 144</br>
                                     carlet -36</br>
                                      mona - 144</br>
                                      rahul - 510</br

                                   <p>
                                   Thanks</br>

                                   </p>
                                   </body>
                          </html>
```

I tried:

```
for query in _queries:
    # print(query)
    cur.execute(query)
    fetch= cur.fetchone().items()

    names = list(fetch)[0][0]
    car_no= list(fetch)[0][1]
    message = f'''<html>
                                  <head></head>
                                  <body>
                                    <p>Dear Team</p>
                                    <p>Last hour count is</p>
                                    \t{names} - \t{car_no}</p>
                                    </body>
                                </html>'''
    print(message)
```

What should i do to get required output.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't read the entire question, but have you tried `zip`?

Comment: yes i tried zip(names,car_no) but its not worked

Comment: step1: put all the data in a list, step2: convert the list into key value pairs as the odd indexes are names and the even indexes are numbers, step3: use this dictionary to add the required data in HTML, let me know how do you feel about it, there are numerous other methods as well

Answer (score 0):

Here's to get you started

```
import sqlite3


conn = sqlite3.connect("file::memory:")
cursor = conn.cursor()
queries = "SELECT 'name' AS name, 1 as no",

def execute_query(query):
    cursor.execute(query)
    return cursor

list_part = '\n'.join(
    f'<br>{name} - {no}</br>'
    for q in queries
    for name, no in execute_query(q)
)

print(list_part)
```

If your data is aligned the way you're showing then maybe this would work for you.

```
from itertools import tee, islice


def chunks(seq, n):
    s = iter(seq)
    return zip(*(iter(s) for i in range(n)))

data = (
    'name1', 1, 'name2', 2
)

list_part = '\n'.join(
    f'<br>{name} - {no}</br>'
    for name, no in chunks(data, 2)
)

print(list_part)
```

Comment: @royal Define "not working". prints `<br>name - 1</br>` for me.

Comment: ` list_part = '\n'.join(f'<br>{row[0]} - {row[1]}</br>' for q in _queries for row in execute_query(q))`
KeyError: 0

Comment: Well, first of all you've probably changed my code. Second - the only place I see where you can have KeyError is `row[0]` and `row[1]` so maybe somehow your version expects column names instead of indices. You can even unpack row into it's values in comprehension (see updated answer)

Comment: with your updated answer,`for name, no in execute_query(q)`   `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)` this error is coming. I want output mention in required output can you help me top do that

Comment: @royal This says that you have only one column in result set, not two. What are you trying to achieve? Show how your data looks like in database.

Comment: its not in database, actually data comes like mention in input sample from sql queries with str and int. I want to put all in my msg variable which is in html as shown.

Comment: @royal you seem to be need iterating your data by chunks